# Cygnus not starting as a service

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

I've been checking other people's questions regarding config files for cygnus, but still I couldn't make mine work.

Starting cygnus with "service cygnus start" fails.

When I try to start the service the log at /var/log/cygnus/cygnus.log says:

```
Warning: JAVA_HOME is not set!
+ exec /usr/bin/java -Xmx20m -Dflume.log.file=cygnus.log -cp '/usr/cygnus/conf:/usr/cygnus/lib/*:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/*:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/libext/*' -Djava.library.path= com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication -p 8081 -f /usr/cygnus/conf/agent_1.conf -n cygnusagent
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/cygnus/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/cygnus-0.8.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./logs/cygnus.log (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:210)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:131)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:207)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:809)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:735)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:615)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:502)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:547)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:483)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:73)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:254)
    at org.apache.flume.node.Application.<clinit>(Application.java:58)
Starting an ordered shutdown of Cygnus
Stopping sources
All the channels are empty
Stopping channels
Stopping hdfs-channel (lyfecycle state=START)
Stopping sinks
Stopping hdfs-sink (lyfecycle state=START)
```

JAVA_HOME is set and I think the issue is with the config files:

agent_1.conf:

```
cygnusagent.sources = http-source
cygnusagent.sinks = hdfs-sink 
cygnusagent.channels = hdfs-channel

#=============================================
 # source configuration
 # channel name where to write the notification events
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.channels = hdfs-channel
 # source class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
 # listening port the Flume source will use for receiving incoming notifications
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.port = 5050
 # Flume handler that will parse the notifications, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler
 # URL target
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
 # Default service (service semantic depends on the persistence sink)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = def_serv
 # Default service path (service path semantic depends on the persistence sink)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = def_servpath
 # Number of channel re-injection retries before a Flume event is definitely discarded (-1 means infinite retries)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.events_ttl = 10
 # Source interceptors, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts gi
 # TimestampInterceptor, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
 # GroupinInterceptor, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor$Builder
 # Grouping rules for the GroupingInterceptor, put the right absolute path to the file if necessary
 # See the doc/design/interceptors document for more details
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/grouping_rules.conf

# ============================================
 # OrionHDFSSink configuration
 # channel name from where to read notification events
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.channel = hdfs-channel
 # sink class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionHDFSSink
 # Comma-separated list of FQDN/IP address regarding the HDFS Namenode endpoints
 # If you are using Kerberos authentication, then the usage of FQDNs instead of IP addresses is mandatory
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs_host = cosmos.lab.fiware.org
 # port of the HDFS service listening for persistence operations; 14000 for httpfs, 50070 for webhdfs
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs_port = 14000
 # username allowed to write in HDFS
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs_username = MYUSERNAME
 # OAuth2 token
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.oauth2_token = MYTOKEN
 # how the attributes are stored, either per row either per column (row, column)
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.attr_persistence = column
 # Hive FQDN/IP address of the Hive server
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hive_host = cosmos.lab.fiware.org
 # Hive port for Hive external table provisioning
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hive_port = 10000
 # Kerberos-based authentication enabling
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.krb5_auth = false
 # Kerberos username
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.krb5_auth.krb5_user = krb5_username
 # Kerberos password
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.krb5_auth.krb5_password = xxxxxxxxxxxxx
 # Kerberos login file
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.krb5_auth.krb5_login_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/krb5_login.conf
 # Kerberos configuration file
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.krb5_auth.krb5_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/krb5.conf

#=============================================
 # hdfs-channel configuration
 # channel type (must not be changed)
cygnusagent.channels.hdfs-channel.type = memory
 # capacity of the channel
cygnusagent.channels.hdfs-channel.capacity = 1000
 # amount of bytes that can be sent per transaction
cygnusagent.channels.hdfs-channel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

And cygnus_instance_1.conf:

```
CYGNUS_USER=cygnus

CONFIG_FOLDER=/usr/cygnus/conf

CONFIG_FILE=/usr/cygnus/conf/agent_1.conf

# Name of the agent. The name of the agent is not trivial, since it is the base for the Flume parameters 
# naming conventions, e.g. it appears in .sources.http-source.channels=...
AGENT_NAME=cygnusagent

# Name of the logfile located at /var/log/cygnus.
LOGFILE_NAME=cygnus.log

# Administration port. Must be unique per instance
ADMIN_PORT=8081

# Polling interval (seconds) for the configuration reloading
POLLING_INTERVAL=30
```

I hope it's a simple issue. If more info is needed please let me know.

BTW, I got my token following the instructions on [this link](http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/BigData_Analysis_-_User_and_Programmer_Guide#OAuth2-protected_REST_APIs_usage).
Isn't there supposed to be a password field for accessing COSMOS global instance? Or is the token enough?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I had to resolve this issue again I will take the opportunity to say how I did it.

Basically log4j needs configuring.
In [this](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus#section7) section of the cygnus repository's instructions for installation and configuration, you can find more details about it.

In my case I'm using only one instance of cygnus to write to an HDFS. To get cygnus to work well, I edited the following line on *CYGNUS_PATH/conf/log4j.properties* to an absolute path where there is a *cygnus.log* file:

```
flume.log.dir=/usr/cygnus/logs
```

Where /user/cygnus is my CYGNUS_PATH.

So now log4j will write cygnus' operations to */usr/cygnus/logs/cygnus.log*.
Of course you're free to put the log file anywhere you want, as long as you reference it correctly on this property file.

Hope this helps anyone with similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

though have not work much on cygnus long time, but the issue which you have mention is looks like while starting the Cygnus your application is not able to locate log directory, for which the Service is not able to start. {which is to be configuration issue.}

to avoid the same you can perform some steps which could help.

1. start the cygnus service from home directory of cygnus if logs directory is also accessable.
   **e.g let say your home directory of cygnus is "/usr/local/cygnus" and log "/usr/local/cygnus/logs/" then start the cygnus service from cygnus home directory it self**
   **"sh /usr/local/cygnus/bin/cygnus start", these will work as the log directory will be access by cygnus "./log/cygnus.log"**
2. add Cygnus Home in ./~bashprofile and  update do export, so these will set Classpath for Cygnus Home directory which will help to access the log location as well so that you can start service by using "service cygnus start".
3. update the configuration for logging of cygnus by mentioning the Full Path of Log location **e.g "/usr/local/cygnus/logs/" and start the service.**

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. We managed to get the log files going right before you posted your answer. Now cygnus is running, but I'm having issues with it writing to the HDFS (A question for another post).
Because I didn't test your suggestion I didn't make it accepted, but I upvoted it. Thank you.